# Kate shows no icon on task manager but it shows it on pager

Tags: icons, kde, kate

I'm running KDE neon 5.7 and `kate` doesn't show the icon on the task manager, but in the pager it's showing ok.

I already reinstalled `kate` with:

```
sudo apt-get purge kate
sudo apt-get install kate
```

But it doesn't fix the missing icon problem.

[image: Click here to see an image of my actual task manager and pager]

As you can see in the image the icon would be in the left of where **Untitled - Kate** is located on the task manager.

In the pager the icon is showing ok on desktop 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After upgrade to KDE neon User Edition 5.9 everything is working now!